# Synonymise [navigationlink] with [swiftui-navigationlink]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I propose to move [navigationlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/navigationlink) into [swiftui-navigationlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiftui-navigationlink).

[navigationlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/navigationlink):

- 83 questions in total
- all questions are related with SwiftUI
- most of them has already [swiftui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiftui) tag (even if there's no [swiftui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiftui) tag, they're still related - eg. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61164067/problems-with-passing-data-in-another-view-how-can-i-filter-users-selections))

[swiftui-navigationlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiftui-navigationlink):

- 214 questions in total
- most SwiftUI-specific tags has the `swiftui-` prefix ([swiftui-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiftui-form), [swiftui-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiftui-list)...)

I'm posting this here as there may not be enough active users who can vote on this tag.

Comment: Grrr... sorry, this wasn't the post, but the other one. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400292/792066 BTW, if removing a prefix would make the tag ambiguous, better not to remove the prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked out the questions tagged [navigationlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/navigationlink) and it looks like all of them were related to SwiftUI Navigation Link. In fact, out of the 83 questions in that tag, 80 questions had the [swiftui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiftui) tag on them. This leads to the question whether having the prefix "swiftui-" on the tag is required or not. As Shog once said, it is better to have unprefixed tags whenever possible.

Anyway in this case, I approved [navigationlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/navigationlink) as a synonym for [swiftui-navigationlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiftui-navigationlink), as the latter tag had a better wiki as well as a larger number of questions.

[navigationlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/navigationlink) (× 83) → [swiftui-navigationlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiftui-navigationlink) (× 213)

I'll merge the tags after a few days. For now, enjoy your Synonymizer badge!