# What should be done to [navigationview]?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-disambiguation

For a long time the [navigationview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/navigationview) tag referred only to the Android component - this is the current tag description:

> Provides navigation drawer access. Part of Android's design support
> library.

However, recently (1 year ago) SwiftUI introduced its own `NavigationView` component.

This resulted in [navigationview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/navigationview) being referred in SwiftUI questions as well:

- 419 questions tagged [navigationview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/navigationview) are also tagged [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)
- 88 questions tagged [navigationview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/navigationview) are also tagged [swiftui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiftui)

There is now a SwiftUI-specific tag [swiftui-navigationview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiftui-navigationview) but it's not likely to be used more than the [navigationview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/navigationview).

What should be done to the [navigationview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/navigationview)?

- change its description to be more general - both for Android and SwiftUI
- or nothing - this would require retagging new SwiftUI questions from [navigationview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/navigationview) to [swiftui-navigationview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiftui-navigationview)

**EDIT**

I've now realised there is also [ios-navigationview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-navigationview) which serves the same purpose as [swiftui-navigationview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiftui-navigationview).

Comment: You need to also consider UWP application. From my view, it seems that the only way is to create [*-navigationview]. All three examples I've found are big topics all on their own. Of course, we could also do without them and use instead [swiftui] [winui] and [material-components-android] which is the higher level these live under.

Comment: @Braiam On the other hand if you look at [tabview] it's used in Android, SwiftUI and JSF. And its description is more general: *Any visual layout that incorporates selectable tabs as an organizational element.*

Comment: If Navigation View refers to the same UI component in all the different usages, then having a single [tag:navigationview] is the correct way to go. If they refer to different things in android, swift and windows, then use the prefix based tags.

Comment: No @BhargavRao if that were the case, we should have one tag: programming, since at the end that's the thing that means the same for all things asked here (that are not off topic). If anything, I prefer not having a tag than generic tags.

Comment: @pawello2222 having a bad tag shouldn't be used to allow yet another bad tag. Tags are not keywords, they should be meaningful, unambiguous and concrete, something both examples you present aren't.

Comment: @Braiam I understand what you're saying - but assuming that SwiftUI questions should be tagged [swiftui-navigationview] then what is [navigationview]? Shouldn't it be [android-navigationview]? And even then new questions [navigationview] will be created anyway.

Comment: @BhargavRao Ideally yes, but suppose tomorrow there will be a new NavigationView component in some other framework which will refer to something else than in SwiftUI/Android. I'd prefer to have [swiftui-navigationview] for SwiftUI questions but I can't *force* anyone to use it - I'd need to maually retag most questions (and I can't retag them inline yet).

Comment: I'm not saying that we need to have a generic tag like [ui-component] for all the UI components, @Braiam. Having a single [navigationview] makes the most sense here if it is the same component in all the different usages. Having prefixed tags just for the sake of it, would make the tags too narrow, and undiscoverable soon. We've been through this a lot of times, and you seem to be very obstinate about this. Prefixed tags are fine, if navigationview was different in the different cases, which however, seems to be unlikely.

Comment: If that's the case, then we can change it when such a thing occurs, @pawello2222. We don't need to make changes right now hoping that someone sometime in the future would create something like that.

Comment: @BhargavRao Ok, so you're suggesting to change the [navigationview] description to be more universal. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I'm suggesting that.

Comment: @BhargavRao Does it also mean [swiftui-navigationview] should be removed and its questions retagged to [navigationview]?

Comment: You don't need to remove and retag, we can just merge the two tags and it would be automatically retagged.

Comment: @BhargavRao Ok, please merge them.

Comment: I would like to wait for some community consensus before taking any hasty decisions. Let's see what others want to say about this.

Comment: No pawello, I said that maybe we don't need a tag for each common or specific term of every language. For example, do you really believe that there's something to be gained to create a tag for every swiftui element, small and big?

Comment: On the other hand I'm thinking now that the [navigationview] tag will have no use on its own. You can't just search by [navigationview] - you need to include a platform tag ([android] etc) as well. Is this the right approach?

Comment: @Braiam No, but there is [navigationview] already and it's used incorrectly. I'd like to do something about it. I don't know what's better. But I know the current way is wrong.

Comment: Well, you also made the other part of the argument yourself pawello, if there's no [navigationview] (in any of its form) is anything lost?

Comment: @Braiam There might be in Android. I don't know how it's used in relation to Android questions. What I know is that it's used incorrectly in SwiftUI questions and I'd like to resolve it.

Comment: Again, if it was removed from all questions, would that solve your issue with swiftui questions?

Comment: @Braiam Yes, this tag is useful (when combined with platform tag) but not necessary. However, if we remove this tag now, it will probably be created again in the near future. I thought this question was easier when I posted it...

Comment: I recommend you to read the create tag help page: "you should only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question **covers a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site**." If swiftui is enough to cover navigationview, and you can't make a strong case about it, it probably shouldn't have been created in the first place.

Comment: @Braiam I understand - so the best solution is to change the description of [navigationview] to be more universal and merge [swiftui-navigationview] into [navigationview] - am I right?

Comment: No, the opposite: remove the tag. Don't think in binary, there are many options: nothing, disambiguate, rename, delete. You can propose any of those.

Comment: @BhargavRao So... should [swiftui-navigationview] be merged into [navigationview]? Removing both tags (suggested by Braiam) doesn't feel like the best option - it will work only for a while but surely [navigationview] will be created again.

Comment: If it's created again, we can deal with that. Merging on the other hand, can't be reversed. Tag removal can be maintained.

Comment: @Braiam I just don't know how this removal may impact Android/JSF. I feel like merging SwiftUI tags is controlled - I have a good knowledge what's being used in SwiftUI but not in other technologies. And the complete removal of all *navigationview tags may not be desired - what if someone wants to search by navigationview in SwiftUI? They may use [navigationview]+[swiftui] tags - without [navigationview] there's only a manual search.

Comment: And I thought this whole process will be easier - there are some opposite recommendations, but how will it be decided what to do? As it's only two of you who responded.

Comment: That's an issue that Android and JSF communities seems to be not worried about. If they do not worry, then maybe is because it doesn't affect them (they may have their own tags, or don't feel the need of having one).

Comment: @Braiam Currently [navigationview] is for Android questions only (according to the description). So there is nothing for Android community to worry about.

Comment: What I meant was about removing the tag: remember, that it takes a single user to edit the tag excerpt, and that doesn't assure you they even have any knowledge about it.